# Python value counts and return the other columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I just started doing my first ML project with Python, and got stuck with one issue.
[image]
My project is to analyze some animal shelter information. Above is the list of animals have been bought to the shelter. I want to see which animals(based on animal ID) have been bought to the shelter more than 3 times, and then return the dataframe with animal ID, breed, MonthYear information etc. My first attempt:

```
aac[aac['Animal ID'].value_counts()>3]
```

After this code, Python tells me:
IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match

My second attempt:

```
temp=df.groupby('Animal ID').count() 
temp[temp['Name']>3]
```

Now I get the following output : [image]

Now I do have the list of animal ID who has been returned to shelter more than 3 times. But I miss the other breed/datatime/monthyear ...information. My question is what is the best way to link animal ID and the other information: breed, monthyear, animaltype etc together. So I can further analyze the returned animals.

Thanks a lot for helping me out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `groupby` operation is not required here.

You can create a `value_counts` series, filter it for items which occur more than 3 times, and then use this to filter your original dataframe.

This is a minimal example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': range(10), 'col2': range(10, 20)},
                  index=['A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'B'])

c = df.index.value_counts()
idx = c[c > 3].index

res = df.loc[df.index.isin(idx)]

print(res)

   col1  col2
A     0    10
A     1    11
B     2    12
A     3    13
B     4    14
A     5    15
B     6    16
B     9    19
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create another column with counts, and use it for filtering.

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({'col1': range(10), 'col2': range(10, 20), 'col3': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'B']})

df = df.merge(df.groupby('col3').apply(len).to_frame(name='counts'), left_on='col3', right_index=True)

df[df.counts > 2]
```